# Spring Lazy Initialization with Spring Cache

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

I'm looking for this behavior using Spring to lazily initialize some constant singletons:

```
Map<String, Status> cache;

public Status getStatus(String name) {
    if (!cache.containsKey(name)) {
        Status status= new Status(name);
        cache.put(name, status);
    }
    return cache.get(name);
}
```

I'm looking at the Spring Caching Guild here: [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/)

And now my method would look like this:

```
@Cacheable
public Status getStatus(String name) {
        return new Status(name);
}
```

And it does what I need, but caching by definition is temporary. I'm wondering if there is too much overhead that can affect performance? Is there a simpler alternative?

Comment: not sure what you want... are you looking for lazy init beans/components [@Lazy](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-lazy-annotation)? or do you want to cache a object?

Comment: Why do you want to initialize constant singletons lazily?